# set or shift background image via css/less for firefox

Tags: css, background, less, background-position

I have the below which works really well for all browsers except Firefox.

Basically it loads a background sprite image and positions it depends on the classes. Is there a work around for Firefox or a better way?

example page - http://smf.jynk.net/events/making-progress-boosting-the-skills-and-wage-prospects-of-the-low-paid/

```
.social__icon--share{
  .svg-bg('smf-site-icons-02',@position: -200px -200px) ;

  .single-publications &{
      background-position-y: -200px;
  }   
  .single-events &{
      background-position-y:-400px;    
  }
  .single-post &{
      background-position-y:-600px;      
  }
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;

  &.social__icon--share--twitter{
    background-position-x: -200px;
  }

  &.social__icon--share--facebook{
    background-position-x: -800px;
  }

  &.social__icon--share--google{
    background-position-x: -1000px;
  }

  &.social__icon--share--linkedin{
    background-position-x: -1200px;
  }

  &.social__icon--share--pinterest{
    background-position-x: -1400px;
  }
```

}

Comment: Can you explain what should happens and what actually happens (and of course add a jsfiddle)?

Comment: basically Firefox needed both x & y at the same time so background-position-y was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround with a mixing -

```
.bgpos(@ypos) {
&.social__icon--share--twitter{
  background-position: -200px @ypos;
}

&.social__icon--share--facebook{
  background-position: -800px @ypos;
}

&.social__icon--share--google{
  background-position: -1000px @ypos;
}

&.social__icon--share--linkedin{
  background-position: -1200px @ypos;
}

&.social__icon--share--pinterest{
  background-position: -1400px @ypos;
}
}
  // icons.less
  .single-publications &{
      .bgpos(-200px);
  }   
  .single-events &{
      .bgpos(-400px);    
  }
  .single-post &{
      .bgpos(-600px);     
  }
```